# Make an Element Visible RobotFramework+Selenium2library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using robotframework+selenium2library to automate an application.

I need to input value into an element which is invisible.

Is there a way using a keyword to make this element visible?

Html for the relevant element:

```
<input class="ng-hide" ng-hide="true" id="upload_file_1" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageChanged(this)" type="file">
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I never encountered this type of situation.
But I think this can be achieve using JavaScript

Robot-framework is using python while in java we can do something like this.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('upload_file_1').style.display="block";");
```

OR

```
    JavascriptExecutor jscript = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jscript.executeScript("$('#upload_file_1').attr('ng-hide','false')");
```

In 2nd code we are setting hidden atribute(ng-hide -> in your case) from true to false using javascript

Do spare me if it won't work for you. It's just an attempt to help you :)